# Is an array of objects meant to be stored in databases or js files?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, storage, user-data

- Here is small sample of an array of objects I use for my site.This isn't the full js file but just snippet.
- I have multiple js files like this and some files are up to 500 lines of code.
- I'm learning about databases and API's currently and was wondering if this should be stored in something like MongoDB?
- This isn't user data but data I have gathered myself.
- Are databases used solely for user data?

  ```
  const pga = []
  pga[0] = {
     name: 'PGA',
     job: 'T.J. Auclair',
     date: '12 Aug 2018',
     players: ['Jack Nicklaus', 'Tiger Woods', 'Bobby Jones',
         'Walter Hagen', 'Sam Snead', 'Ben Hogan',
         'Arnold Palmer', 'Gary Player', 'Gene Sarazen',
         'Phil Mickelson', 'Tom Watson', 'Byron Nelson', 'Billy Casper',
         'Seve Ballesteros', 'Harry Vardon'],
     url: 'https://www.pga.com/news/golf-buzz/10-greatest-golfers-all-
     time',
     pic: 'pga-com'
  }
  ```

Comment: This is an ideal use case for implementing MongoDB or any of the other NoSQL data stores. A great way to learn. But, you might be surprised that with the correct caching put in place you simple flat files will likely outperform a DB.

Comment: Thanks Randy. I will end up putting this data into a DB then. JW but the Flat files with correct caching outperform DB because of the delayed time when fetching data from the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure this can be stored to database as well as the user data.
It just would be better to split your data according to some of your application logic.

E.g. if you will choose Mongo you would create a separate collection for data you collected your self `players` and another collection of your application users named `users`

Comment: Thanks Satir for the input. I will end up doing that for the website.